# How to edit settings.settings connectionString in code?

Tags: c#, winforms, mysql-connector

I currently have a connection string for MySQL saved in the settings.settings file for my winforms program. Since I sometimes change the IP of the server, user, password etc., I want to be able to change this from the program itself.

I made a new form with 4 textboxes that hold each part of the connstring I want to change.

- How do I read the parts of the connstring in settings.settings and put it in the textboxes?
- How do I update the connstring in settings.settings with the new info I input in the textboxes?
- Will this be saved or will it be replaced with the old connstring?

Comment: Did you make it an application scope or user scope?

Comment: @CaiusJard It says it's application scope. I didn't know of this before but now that I've read a bit about it I see that only the user scope can be changed while the application is running. Is this correct?

Comment: True. Consider your settings.settings to be like defaults, and only user scope Ines can be edited and saved during run time. To change app scopes ones you have to edit the config xml file on disk and reload the app or re read the settings.  User scopes setting alterations are saved in some folder buried deep inside the user profile and are a bit of a pain as they can be lost if you upgrade the app. All in I would consider making a Separate encrypted file for storing db entries if I were going o change it a lot or I'd use a host name and use DNS to alter the ip

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! I guess it isn't that great of a idea then as I update the app often. I'll look into the separate file way of doing it. At least I now know the difference between application and user scope. Thanks!

Comment: If you're mad keen on doing it I have in the past had success with editing the file on disk and then reloading the settings while the app is running, but I'd say the existing provision is best suited to a situation where the details won't change by the user, or they will be changed regularly by the user (and hence if they spontaneously revert after an update) it doesn't matter. If you're using something like typed datasets that pull connection strings out of the app settings then it's another reason to use them.. but it feels like you should perhaps develop a "db manager" form and have an..

Comment: ..xml or Json based repository of conn str info. Kinda like FileZilla has an ftp site manager and can remember multiple different servers